# how to use google road api with polyline

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps-api-3, google-roads-api

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script
src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js">
</script>

<script>
var snappedCoordinates = [];
var placeIdArray = [];
var polylines = [];
function initialize()
{
var mapProp = {
  center:{lat: 13.0342, lng: 80.2301},
  zoom:14,
  mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };

var map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"),mapProp);

var myTrip=[{lat: 13.0342, lng: 80.2301},{lat:13.0396077,lng:80.2457392}];
var path = myTrip;
polylines.push(myTrip);
placeIdArray = [];
runSnapToRoad(path);

function drawSnappedPolyline() {
    var flightPath=new google.maps.Polyline({
          path:myTrip,
          strokeColor:"#0000FF",
          strokeOpacity:0.8,
          strokeWeight:2
          });

        flightPath.setMap(map);
        polylines.push(flightPath);
}

function runSnapToRoad(path) {
    var pathValues = [];
      for (var i = 0; i < path.getLength(); i++) {
        pathValues.push(path.getAt(i).toUrlValue());
      }

      $.get('https://roads.googleapis.com/v1/snapToRoads', {
        interpolate: true,
        key: apiKey,
        path: pathValues.join('|')
      }, function(data) {
        processSnapToRoadResponse(data);
        drawSnappedPolyline();
      });
}


function processSnapToRoadResponse(data) {
      snappedCoordinates = [];
      placeIdArray = [];
      for (var i = 0; i < data.snappedPoints.length; i++) {
        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(
            data.snappedPoints[i].location.latitude,
            data.snappedPoints[i].location.longitude);
        snappedCoordinates.push(latlng);
        placeIdArray.push(data.snappedPoints[i].placeId);
      }
    }

}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="googleMap" style="width:500px;height:380px;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

this my code for google road api i got the central map but the road api is not working , i given two point lat,lng how to exact map for road api my exaction link is https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/roads/inspector how to integrated ployline in my code

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing `var apiKey = 'YOUR_API_KEY';` in your code.

**By using Android API:**

> To use the Google Maps Android API, you must register your app project on the Google Developers Console and get a Google API key which you can add to your app.

Follow these [steps](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/signup) to get an API key:

1. Go to the [Google Developers Console](https://pantheon.corp.google.com/flows/enableapi?apiid=maps_android_backend&keyType=CLIENT_SIDE_ANDROID&reusekey=true&pli=1&debugUI=DEVELOPERS).
2. Create or select a project.
3. Click **Continue** to enable the API.
4. **Go to Credentials** to get an **Android key** and set the API credentials.
   Note: If you have an existing **Android key**, you may use that key.
5. In the resulting dialog, enter your app's SHA-1 fingerprint and package name.
   For example:
   `BB:0D:AC:74:D3:21:E1:43:67:71:9B:62:91:AF:A1:66:6E:44:5D:75`
   `com.example.android.mapexample`
6. Your new Android key appears in the list of API keys for your project. An API key is a string of characters, something like this:
   `AIzaSyBdVl-cTICSwYKrZ95SuvNw7dbMuDt1KG0`

**By using JavaScript API:**

> All JavaScript API applications require authentication.

Follow these [steps](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key) to get an API key:

1. Go to the [Google Developers Console](https://pantheon.corp.google.com/flows/enableapi?apiid=maps_android_backend&keyType=CLIENT_SIDE_ANDROID&reusekey=true&pli=1&debugUI=DEVELOPERS).
2. Create or select a project.
3. Click **Continue** to Enable the API.
4. On the **Credentials** page, get a **Browser key** (and set the API Credentials).
   Note: If you have an existing Browser key, you may use that key.
5. To prevent quota theft, [secure your API key following these best practices](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/6310037).
6. (Optional) Enable billing. See [Usage Limits](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/usage) for more information.

Comment: Kanna is using the javascript API, not the Android API.

Comment: I have seen in this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key) that "All JavaScript API applications require authentication."

Comment: sure, but your instructions are just for Android

Comment: I used API key also but the direction is not showing